# Is it possible to add "custom" methods to a primitive data type in python?

Tags: python, methods, types, primitive

For example, if I wanted to make a .isPrime() method for an int (which would return a Boolean value depending on whether the integer was prime)?

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to do? Maybe give a better example

Comment: Yes, it's theoretically possible, but you don't want to do this *(trust me)*..